# GitHub changes (made by build.sbt) no staged for commit

Tags: git, github, sbt, github-for-windows

by defining some lazy val in `build.sbt` file in my project, the directory structure (***empty directory tree***) is created but my GitHub app does not recognize them as changes. I also tried `git add .` but noting added for committing. `.gitignore` file does not restrict them.
I have never had such problem with auto generated files.

I also added a class to one of the folders, still no change in Github app but by `git add .` the change (only that class) is ready to commit but other folders not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

[GIT cannot version directories](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/MarkEmptyDirs)